# Boolean vs tinyint(1) for boolean values in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

What column type is best to use in a MySQL database for boolean values? I use `boolean` but my colleague uses `tinyint(1)`.

Comment: It seems that MySQL transparently treats `boolean` as `tinyint(1)`. So you can use `boolean`, `true` and `false` and MySQL treats them as `tinyint(1)`, `1` and `0`.

Comment: Another case is char 1 with Y & N which is supposed to be faster by some people.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

These data types are synonyms.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html

Comment: I wouldn't say the data _types_ are synonyms -- tinyint(1) is the same as bool, but tinyint and bool are not the same. Minor point, but your answer tripped me up the first time I read it

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. While it's true that tinyint(1) is functionally identical to bool, the OP asked what is best to use. The answer by @dj_segfault does a proper job explaining why bool should be preferred over tinyint(1) when storing a boolean value.

Comment: Indeed, the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html) indicate BOOL and BOOLEAN are synonyms for tinyint(1).

Comment: I would like to mention the docs link in the question, but the edit queue is full now, as usual...

Answer (score 126):

I am going to take a different approach here and suggest that it is just as important for your fellow developers to understand your code as it is for the compiler/database to. Using `boolean` may do the same thing as using `tinyint`, however it has the advantage of *semantically* conveying what your **intention** is, and that's worth something.

If you use a `tinyint`, it's not obvious that the only values you should see are `0` and `1`.
A `boolean` is ALWAYS `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 43):

`boolean` isn't a distinct datatype in MySQL; it's just a synonym for `tinyint`. [See this page in the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html).
See the quotes and examples down below from the `dev.mysql.com/doc/`

> BOOL, BOOLEAN These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero
> is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true:

```
    mysql> SELECT IF(0, 'true', 'false');
    +------------------------+
    | IF(0, 'true', 'false') |
    +------------------------+
    | false                  |
    +------------------------+
    mysql> SELECT IF(1, 'true', 'false');
    +------------------------+
    | IF(1, 'true', 'false') |
    +------------------------+
    | true                   |
    +------------------------+
    mysql> SELECT IF(2, 'true', 'false');
    +------------------------+
    | IF(2, 'true', 'false') |
    +------------------------+
    | true                   |
    +------------------------+
```

> However, the values TRUE and FALSE are merely aliases for 1 and 0, respectively, as shown here:

```
mysql> SELECT IF(0 = FALSE, 'true', 'false');
+--------------------------------+
| IF(0 = FALSE, 'true', 'false') |
+--------------------------------+
| true                           |
+--------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT IF(1 = TRUE, 'true', 'false');
+-------------------------------+
| IF(1 = TRUE, 'true', 'false') |
+-------------------------------+
| true                          |
+-------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT IF(2 = TRUE, 'true', 'false');
+-------------------------------+
| IF(2 = TRUE, 'true', 'false') |
+-------------------------------+
| false                         |
+-------------------------------+
mysql> SELECT IF(2 = FALSE, 'true', 'false');
+--------------------------------+
| IF(2 = FALSE, 'true', 'false') |
+--------------------------------+
| false                          |
+--------------------------------+
```

> The last two statements display the results shown because 2 is equal
> to neither 1 nor 0.

Personally I would suggest use tinyint as a preference, because boolean doesn't do what you think it does from the name, so it makes for potentially misleading code. But at a practical level, it really doesn't matter -- they both do the same thing, so you're not gaining or losing anything by using either.

Comment: Although this is a very thorough response, at the end you share your preference for `tinyint`, stating "boolean doesn't do what you think it does from the name". Can you elaborate?

I find this answer very good on this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47404140/2099911): "...(boolean) carries the semantic meaning of what you're trying to do".

Answer (score 9):

use **enum** its the easy and fastest

i will not recommend enum or tinyint(1) as bit(1) needs only 1 bit for storing boolean value while tinyint(1) needs 8 bits.

ref

[TINYINT vs ENUM(0, 1) for boolean values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546186/tinyint-vs-enum0-1-for-boolean-values-in-mysql)

Comment: We can't use enum as our database also needs to support sqlite

Comment: If you are using InnoDB, bit ends up using just as much space as tinyint. From [High Performance MySQL](http://www.amazon.com/High-Performance-MySQL-Optimization-Replication/dp/1449314287/) (the percona guys) "InnoDB store[s] each [bit] column as the smallest integer type large enough to contain the bits, so you don't save any storage space." The only gain is if you are storing multiple boolean values in a BIT(morethan1) column. So if you only have one boolean field, using tinyint is the same as bit in InnoDB, and is preferable since tinyint is typically easier to work with.

Comment: Not true for MySQL: `BIT(M) - approximately (M+7)/8 bytes` see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Answer (score 8):

While it's true that `bool` and `tinyint(1)` are *functionally* identical, `bool` should be the preferred option because it carries the semantic meaning of what you're trying to do. Also, many ORMs will convert `bool` into your programing language's native boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

My experience when using **Dapper** to connect to **MySQL** is that **it does matter**. I changed a non nullable bit(1) to a nullable tinyint(1) by using the following script:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName MODIFY Setting BOOLEAN null;
```

Then Dapper started throwing Exceptions. I tried to look at the difference before and after the script. And noticed the bit(1) had changed to tinyint(1).

I then ran:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName CHANGE COLUMN Setting Setting BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Which solved the problem.

Comment: Dapper is just an application that probably doesn't know how to read the boolean definition in mysql.  That is very different than there actually being a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you choose int or bool it matters especially when nullable column comes into play.

Imagine a product with multiple photos. How do you know which photo serves as a product cover? Well, we would use a column that indicates it.

So far out `product_image` table has two columns: `product_id` and `is_cover`

Cool? Not yet. Since the product can have only one cover we need to add a unique index on these two columns.

But wait, if these two column will get an unique index how would you store many non-cover images for the same product? The unique index would throw an error here.

So you may though "Okay, but you can use NULL value since these are ommited by unique index checks", and yes this is truth, but we are loosing linguistic rules here.

What is the purpose of NULL value in boolean type column? Is it "all", "any", or "no"? The null value in boolean column allows us to use the unique index, but it also messes up how we interpret the records.

I would tell that in some cases the integer can serve a better purpose since its not bound to strict true or false meaning

Comment: Your logic is flawed.  Integer means a number.  Null means we don't have that number or its not applicable. Bit has the exact same logic.  It's either True or False (1 or 0).  Null would mean we don't know what it is, or its not applicable. 

Some applications treat Null the same as False.  Instead they should have just used false as a default value..

Answer (score 0):

You can controll the behavor by add parameter to jdbc-url:

`tinyInt1isBit=false`

The `tinyInt1isBit=false` parameter in a JDBC URL is related to how MySQL handles the TINYINT(1) data type. Let’s break it down:

TINYINT(1):

- In MySQL, the TINYINT data type can store integer values from -128 to 127 (signed) or 0 to 255 (unsigned).
- When you define a TINYINT column with a length of 1 (e.g., TINYINT(1)), it is often used to represent boolean values (true or false).
- By default, when retrieving data from a TINYINT(1) column, MySQL maps it to a Java Boolean type (true or false).

If tinyInt1isBit is set to true (which is the default behavior), the driver converts `TINYINT(1)` columns to Java Boolean values.
If you set tinyInt1isBit to false, the driver converts TINYINT(1) columns to Java Integer values instead of Boolean.

If you want to retrieve this value as an Integer (0 or 1) rather than a Boolean, you can add tinyInt1isBit=false to your JDBC URL.
Here’s an example of how you might include this parameter in your JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?tinyInt1isBit=false
```