# How to custom the type of value in the map returned by jdbcTemplate.queryForMap()?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbctemplate

Suppose I hava a table with a column named status whose type is `tinyint(1)`, and I use the following jdbc query to get a specific row from database, but now the `queryForMap()` method here will auto convent the `tinyint(1)` status field to the type `boolean`, but in fact I'm not only going to use this field to save 0 or 1 (also store value 2 for example), so I would prefer this type of status to be `byte`. How can I achieve this goal?

```
Map<String, Object> task = jdbcTemplate
        .queryForMap("select * from task where id = ? and deleted = 0 for update", taskId);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does TINYINT(1) function as a boolean but INT(1) does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798744/why-does-tinyint1-function-as-a-boolean-but-int1-does-not)

Comment: @TKJohn I suppose not..TINYINT can store -128 to 127, I only want to get the byte value from mysql instead of translating it into boolean

Comment: Sorry I should be more specific https://stackoverflow.com/a/35488212/6521058

Comment: @TKJohn, But I'm not creating table in this case

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses `tinyint(1)` as an alias of `boolean`. So driver of mysql will treat `tinyint(1)` as `boolean` value. You can disable this future by adding `tinyInt1isBit=false` to your connection url (as description in the link above). After that you will get `Integer` of the `tinyint(1)` column. But I suggest obey the alias, and define your table as `tinyint` or `tinyint(4)` to identify it's not `boolean`.