# why mysql conver bool into tinyint(1) instead it should be bool into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

When I was using type as bool when creating table it was directly converted into tinyint (1) , I don't know exact deference why mysql convert it into tinyint instead of datatype bool ?

Comment: For more information see: [Boolean vs tinyint(1) for boolean values in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751853/boolean-vs-tinyint1-for-boolean-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BOOL is equivalents of TINYINT(1). TINYINT Uses the smallest integer data type.

so whenever you try to create table with **boolean** datatype it automatically gets converted to **inttype**

```
e.g.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` 
(
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `p_description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `p_status` bool NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE
)
```

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 3):

TINYINT Uses the smallest integer data type .

BOOL is equivalents of TINYINT(1).