# PDO Insert not accepting "true" or "false", but only 0 and 1

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phinx

After introducing phinx as a database migration tool, I am no longer able to use *true* and *false* through PDO's execute statement. Whenever I do, I get the following error:

> PHP Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'my_db'.'my_table'.'my_column' at row 1...

My table has the following schema (shorted):

```sql
| Field                         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| my_column                     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am using the following code (shorted):

```php
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table` (`my_column`) VALUES (:mycolumn)");
$stmt->execute([
   'my_column' => false
]);
```

The column is created by the migration script with:

```
->addColumn('my_column', 'boolean', [
  'null' => false,
  'after' => 'another_column',
])
```

The strange thing is, that I have no problems with using *true* and *false* in manual sql statements through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Just make sure the `$table` is properly escaped, by the way.

Comment: By the way, define default value when you are creating a column

Answer (score 2):

you can use `PDO::PARAM_BOOL` in [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

```
$stmt->bindValue(':myColumn', false, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
```

Comment: Yes, most likely I should do that. However, it isn't exactly the fix I need. I have got this problem at many places throughout my application, which means I would have to change it everywhere as far as I understood. The answer by Red Bottle fixed it for me however. I don't want to accept that either however, because I believe it wasn't downvoted without reason. I don't know why it would be practice though, if I include the command in my migration file. If you could adapt your solution to work in my entire application without making changes everywhere, I could accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when i use **macOS**,

i was building my website from **Windows** **10**, and works fine.
After using **macOS** i had to change the variables to `1` or `0`

I hope you fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

A solution to that problem is to set `sql_mode = ''` globally.

Run this query in you DB and check if it fixes the issue:

```
set GLOBAL sql_mode = "";
```

You can read up on [Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) here

P.S. you have to run that query everytime you restart your mysql server. To overcome this you have to set it in mysql config which you can look it up if required.

Comment: That fixed it for me! Can you elaborate a bit more on what it does exactly? Does it have something to do with how MySQL parses commands?

Comment: shared the link to the doc for your reference

Answer (score -2):

Your field type is tinyint(1). so it supports only values from 0-9 . Change to to varchar, text, char etc to accept true/false string.
But i strongly suggest you to use bool datatype. Then use 0 or 1 as true or false. There is no point in writing string (true/false) values for boolean operations. Using 0 or 1 will save you from lot of troubles in the future.

Comment: As far as my research goes, boolean is internally represented as tinyint(1) by MySQL. I am referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751853/boolean-vs-tinyint1-for-boolean-values-in-mysql).

Comment: This is just wrong. tinyint always supports [-128,127] or [0,255] unsigned. The number in brackets is the display width and is afaik only for ZEROFILL, nothing else. A column of tinyint(1) will display 1 with ZEROFILL. tinyint(2): 01, tinyint(3): 001 ...