# how to implement tinyInt(1) in python django models file

Tags: python, django-models

how to implement tinyInt(1) in python Django models file. I have tried like below but they give me the error.
models.tinyInt1()

Comment: `models.BooleanField`?

Answer (score 0):

Django model fields are supposed to be unaware of the SQL dialect of the database. This thus means that the database backend will transform this to the respective SQL column type.

A `BooleanField` is conceptually equivalent to a `tinyint(1)`, since a `BooleanField` requires one bit: `True` if it has `1` as value, and `0` for `False`. In SQL dialects like MySQL, [a `tinyint` is equivalent to a `boolean`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3751853/67579).

Your model thus can implement this as:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    condition = models.BooleanField()
```